# Element getting bind twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first time asking here, and yes this means i have exhausted my options.
Im currently working on a script which modifies and element's css properties dynamically. I'm having problems with the script changing the css properties of both(i placed two elements in the example) elements instead of just only one of the elements.
So here's how it happens:

1. Change one element's css. It was changed correctly
2. Try to change the next element's css
3. Both elements now have the same css of the latter element.

here are the functions that i have made:

Open contextmenu (using middle mouse)

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.openMenu = function(opt) {

        console.log(x+" "+y);

        $('#contextmenu').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $('#contextmenu').css( 'top', y );
        $('#contextmenu').css( 'left', x );
        $('#contextmenu').show();
        $('#close_context').on("click", function(){

                $('#contextmenu').hide();
            });
        $("#addContent").on("click", function(){
                $('#contextmenu').hide();

        });
        $('#deleteElement').on("click", function(){
            element.remove();

            $('#contextmenu').hide();
        });
        $('#contextmenu').unbind();
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Actual code that changes the css

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.modifyCssElement = function() {
        var element = this;
        console.log(this.attr('id'));
        $('#border').val(element.css("border"));
        $('#padding').val(element.css("padding"));
        $('#z-index').val(element.css("z-index"));
        $('#border-radius').val(element.css("border-radius"));


        var elembg = this.css('background');
        $("#padding").focusout( function(){
            element.css('padding', "");
            element.css('padding', $(this).val());

        });

        $("#border-radius").change( function(){
            element.css('-webkit-border-radius', "");
            element.css('-moz-border-radius', "");
            element.css('border-radius', "");
            element.css('-webkit-border-radius', $(this).val());
            element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());
            element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());


        });
        $("#border").change( function(){
            element.css('border', "");
            element.css('border', $(this).val());
            console.log(element.attr('id'));

        });
        $("#z-index").change( function(){
            element.css('z-index', "");
            element.css('z-index', $(this).val());

        });

        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

here's a fiddle of the script:

https://jsfiddle.net/092swmxj/1/

Comment: use `.off` instead of `.unbind`. `.unbind` only works if event binded with `.bind()`

Comment: already tried `.off` before, didn't work too ;(

Comment: @Jaycroll i think you are trying to solve the problem without looking for the root cause of problem mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove previously setup handlers in your `modifyCssElement` function.

e.g.

```
$("#padding").off('focusout').focusout( function(){

...

$("#border-radius").off('change').change( function(){
```

This is because you are reusing the same HTML elements for your context menu. When you call `focusout`, etc it does not override previous handlers. Each call is adding a listener handler to the HTML element, To stop this you have to explicitly remove previous handlers (using `off`) otherwise all previously added will get fired.

Comment: Youre right it worked O>o no wonder it wasnt working before. I was calling `.off()` on `#contextmenu` rather than the input elements. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As answered by George, you have to unbind the event listeners on then input fields so that the previous listeners can be removed. The problem with your code is that an event listener is attached to the input elements like `$("#padding")` every time the `modifyCssElement` function is executed.

So to solve this problem when you do `$('#contextmenu').hide()` you have to execute extra code to remove the previous event listeners, as such:

```
$("#padding, #border-radius, #border, #z-index").off()
```

Edit: no need for the .off("**")

Comment: I tried this in the JSFiddle, it works, but only if you modify the call to just `.off();`,  not `.off("**");` if you want to use the "**", you need to specify the event you want to remove all handlers from, namely `.off("change","**");`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you are writing events inside your `modifyCssElement` function, i tried this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1y0756r/) and it is working fine.

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var element;
    $.fn.modifyCssElement = function() {
      element = this;

      $('#border').val(element.css("border"));
      $('#padding').val(element.css("padding"));
      $('#z-index').val(element.css("z-index"));
      $('#border-radius').val(element.css("border-radius"));


      var elembg = this.css('background');


      return this;
  };

  $("#padding").focusout( function(){
        element.css('padding', "");
        element.css('padding', $(this).val());

 });

    $("#border-radius").change( function(){
    console.log(element);
        element.css('-webkit-border-radius', "");
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', "");
        element.css('border-radius', "");
        element.css('-webkit-border-radius', $(this).val());
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());


    });
    $("#border").change( function(){
        element.css('border', "");
        element.css('border', $(this).val());
        console.log(element.attr('id'));

    });
    $("#z-index").change( function(){
        element.css('z-index', "");
        element.css('z-index', $(this).val());

    });

}( jQuery ));
```

A new copy of events getting registered everytime you call the function `modifyCssElement` i tried this for debugging purpose

```
$("#border-radius").change( function(){
    console.log("huhahha");
        element.css('-webkit-border-radius', "");
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', "");
        element.css('border-radius', "");
        element.css('-webkit-border-radius', $(this).val());
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());
        element.css('-moz-border-radius', $(this).val());


    });
```

and the output in `console` was `huhahha` getting printed in incremental number, one time for the first change in border-radius, two times for second change in border-radius and so on... so I think your events are getting attached not just two times, they are getting attached number of times you are pressing the `mousewheel`

[image: Screenshot for reference]